# Search lines in text file for pattern between two positions and print entire row

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

How can I search lines in a text file for a pattern between two positions and print the entire row where that pattern is found? I am working with fixed-width files. I understand how to supply a list of lengths for each field to `awk`, but I am only interested in searching a single field for the pattern. Is there a simpler solution that does not involve specifying the length for each field?

Here is a single line of text from the file. How can I find all lines that have 'Cook Co. IL' between positions 18 and 57 and not elsewhere in the line?

```
17 031 1602 1600 Cook Co. IL                              047 011 9999 9999 Bradley Co. TN                                16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'substr($0,18,57-18)~/Cook Co\. IL/' file
```

---

> ***substr(string, start [, length ])***
>  Return a ***length***-character-long substring of ***string***, starting at character
>   number ***start***.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard to specify field widths, given that you only want to consider the line as three fields (0-17, 18-57, 58+):

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="17 40"  -e '$2 ~ /Cook Co\. IL/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 'h; s/./&\n/57; /^.\{17\}.*Cook Co[.] IL.*\n/!d; g' yourfile
```

Mark out the right-boundary and constrain using ^ the left boundary. Within this region look for the regex. If found, print the hold which has orig. line.